# pyodbc connect driver name

Tags: python, macos, driver, pyodbc

Does somebody have an idea where can I find driver name for "pyodbc.connect " function?

```
self.cur = pyodbc.connect(driver='{??????????????????????}',
                                  host='localhost',
                                  port=3307,
                                  user='root',
                                  password='',
                                  database='test_db')
```

Where can I find the name of that driver on Mac OS X?

Comment: You haven't specified what kind of database you want to connect to, so it's impossible to say.

Comment: I want to connect to MySQL database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You usually download the MySQL connector from the [official site](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/). See the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-installation-binary-osx.html) for installing under Mac OS X. The driver name is `"MySQL ODBC 5.2 Driver"`.

If you're not working with other database engines, consider using a more specific package such as [pymysql](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyMySQL) or [MySQLdb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/).

Comment: I went throught entire instalation proces and I find out that by instaling iODBC library I get iODBC manager where can you easily find out all drivers connected to this problem.